# ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, perl

I am working on a Perl script which uses `mysqldiff` to compare two databases and then apply changes to the first database. The command I am using:

```
mysqldiff --host=$dbHost --user=$dbUser -A $dbName1 $dbName2
```

I am getting the difference but after that there is the following error happens always:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database <NAME OF THE DATABASE>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like $dbUser is empty

Comment: No, I have assigned value to $dbUser.

Answer (score 0):

Do i asume right you get at least following message?:

> nApply above changes to $db0 [y/N] ?

if yes it seems like the auth_args from [MySQL::Diff](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ESTRABD/MySQL-Diff-0.60/lib/MySQL/Diff.pm) doesn't work. 
You can try to use the alternative Statements:

> GetOptions(\%opts, "help|?", "debug|d:i", "apply|A", "batch-apply|B",
>              "keep-old-tables|k", "keep-old-columns|c", "no-old-defs|n",
>              "only-both|o", "table-re|t=s",
>              "host|h=s", "port|P=s", "socket|s=s", "user|u=s", "password|p:s",
>              "host1=s",  "port1=s",  "socket1=s",  "user1=s",  "password1:s",
>              "host2=s",  "port2=s",  "socket2=s",  "user2=s",  "password2:s",
>              "tolerant|i", "single-transaction|S", "list-tables|l"
>             )

(see sourcecode)

If this doesn't work try to start it in debug mode with

> -d,  --debug

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for answering. I am very new to building Perl scripts. Could you please explain how can I use the Alternative Statements?